# Utilizing OOP to create an active list of objects

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and I'm trying to understand how to utilize classes to create and update a list of a ship that is created on initialization and ships created while running the program. The examples that I could find that were similar shows a list that was hard coded in from the beginning, but it doesn't show anything about adding onto the list while running.

I've spent the last week trying to figure this out and I have not been able to.

This is my current class

```
public class Ship
{
    private string? _Name;
    private int _ShipY;
    private int _ShipX;
    private int _CameraY;
    private int _CameraX;
    private int _Type;
    private int _Direction;
    private int _MaxHealth;
    private int _CurrentHealth;
    private bool _Active;
    private int _ID;
```

Comment: _"...to create and update a list of a ship that is created on initialization and ships created while running the program..."_ - huh?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When posting, just focus on the immediate problem.  Posts are not meant to be a _diary_.   All that VBA stuff was irrelevant.

Comment: I apologize for the irrelevant information; future questions will be clearer and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use List.Add for adding object values to class list like this:

```
List<Ship> Ships = new List<Ship>(); 
Ship ship = new Ship(_Name, _ShipY, _ShipX, _CameraY, _CameraX, _Type, _MaxHealth, _CurrentHealth, _Active, _ID); //Class Cunstrauctor

Ships.Add(ship);
```